# NAS4Free and SMB not allows me to access shared folders

Tags: freebsd, smb

I have some troubles trying to create a chared folder on my server hosted with NAS4Free.

I enabled the CIFS/SMB service:

[image]

Create some shares:

[image]

However if I try to access to these folders from my laptop typing `\\192.168.1.250` in the explorer path string and trying several username/password combinations including: netbios name and nas4free admin password, ftp (as a guest username) but I have to access.

What is the right user name and password? Or I did something in a wrong way?